# Ler retorno de API em um JSONObject em caso de erros na URL

Tags: java, json

Estou tentando consumir uma API de previsão do tempo (https://openweathermap.org/current) em Java porém estou com uma dúvida referente ao retorno do `JSONObject`.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para gerar o `JSONObject`:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

E quando eu coloco uma URL válida (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=sao+paulo&appid=ccad5d6394c0ebed411edff3fccecb67&lang=pt&units=metric) dá certo, consigo manipular sem problemas.

Porém quando utilizo uma URL inválida (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ABCD&appid=ccad5d6394c0ebed411edff3fccecb67&lang=pt&units=metric) a API me retorna um JSON com a informação do código 404, porém no navegador ele acusa o seguinte erro:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

E no IDE o seguinte erro:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ABCD&appid=ccad5d6394c0ebed411edff3fccecb67&lang=pt&units=metric
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1153) ~[commons-io-2.5.jar:2.5]
```

A pergunta é, ao invés de dar o erro status 500 (Internal Server Error), não deveria me retornar o JSON com a informação do erro 404? Como posso contornar esse problema recebendo o erro 404 de não encontrado para poder tratar no código?

Comment: Posso estar redondamente enganado, mas, creio eu que como o navegador só "exibe" o que o java mandou os erros gerados pelo navegador são outros.

Comment: Na realidade é um servidor criado com Spring e Maven, então quando eu faço a requisição, ele representa o erro do servidor no navegador, por isso eu acho que fazendo a verificação com **conn.getResponseCode()** eu vou conseguir tratar a requisição antes de mesmo de executar o **conn.getInputStream()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acessando a URL inválida no Chrome, o retorno foi o JSON:

```js
{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}
```

Mas se olharmos no *Developer Tools* (aperte <kbd>F12</kbd>), na aba *Network*, veremos que a URL retorna o código HTTP 404:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o `IOUtils` lança exceção quando recebe algum código de erro. A solução, neste caso, seria verificar antes o código de erro e usar o *stream* correto de acordo com o seu valor:

```
public void readUrl(String url) {
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        // verificar o código de retorno
        InputStream in;
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            in = conn.getInputStream();
        } else {
            // se deu erro, ler do error stream
            in = conn.getErrorStream();
        }
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        System.out.println(obj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // tratar erros de conexão
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
// URL válida
readUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=sao+paulo&appid=ccad5d6394c0ebed411edff3fccecb67&lang=pt&units=metric");
// URL inválida
readUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ABCD&appid=ccad5d6394c0ebed411edff3fccecb67&lang=pt&units=metric");
```

A saída é:

```js
{"visibility":10000,"timezone":-10800,"main":{"temp":12.04,"temp_min":11,"humidity":87,"pressure":1027,"temp_max":15},"clouds":{"all":75},"sys":{"country":"BR","sunrise":1563443236,"sunset":1563482272,"id":8394,"type":1,"message":0.0077},"dt":1563449497,"coord":{"lon":-46.64,"lat":-23.55},"weather":[{"icon":"04d","description":"nuvens quebradas","main":"Clouds","id":803}],"name":"Sao Paulo","cod":200,"id":3448439,"base":"stations","wind":{"deg":90,"speed":5.1}}
{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}
```

Se quiser, você pode optar por não ler do *error stream* e tomar alguma outra ação, fica a seu critério.

---

Repare no uso de `finally` para garantir que a conexão seja fechada ao final da execução do método (você também poderia ter fechado o `InputStream`, a diferença é que `disconnect` [não permite que a conexão seja reusada posteriormente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767973)).

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava, no caso então do erro, o certo seria ao invés de tentar ler com **getInputStream()**, utilizar o **getErrorStream()** para obter o retorno e tratar desta maneira. Vou implementar no meu código e fazer o tratamento, obrigado novamente!

Comment: @MarcosCouto Fiz uma alteração no código, tinha esquecido de fechar a conexão...